# DISTINCT one column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

**Hello,**

I have two tables:

> episodes:
>
> - id
> - episode
> - season
> - series
> - title
>
> series:
>
> - id
> - name

I would like to receive last added episodes (without repeating series)

For example:
I added two episode to Walking Dead and one episode to House M.D.

So, result should be:

> Episode 2 - Walking Dead
>
> Episode 1 - House M.D.

My query at this moment is:

```
SELECT *, e.id AS episodeId, s.id AS seriesId 
FROM episodes AS e 
LEFT JOIN series AS s ON e.series = s.id 
ORDER BY e.id DESC LIMIT 25
```

Comment: Use group by seriesId.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: If I use group by series id I get first episode, no last...

Comment: How do you decide the last added episode? by the biggest episode.id?

Comment: Check this question, maybe it has a solution for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using MAX(e.id)

```
SELECT MAX(e.id) AS episodeId, s.id AS seriesId 
FROM episodes AS e 
LEFT JOIN series AS s ON e.series = s.id 
GROUP BY s.id
```

If you need more columns then use a join

```
SELECT * 
FROM episodes AS ep
JOIN
(SELECT MAX(e.id) AS episodeId, s.id AS seriesId 
FROM episodes AS e 
LEFT JOIN series AS s ON e.series = s.id 
GROUP BY s.id) temp
ON temp.episodeId =ep.id
```